# Передвижение объекта в Java с помощью slider

Tags: java, slider

Как осуществить передвижение объекта в Java с помощью `slider`? Т.е. при передвижении ползунка - двигать объект в соответствующую сторону.

Comment: Да, это можно осуществить.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Отлично, ещё один вопрос успешно закрыт -- можно переходить к следующему! ))

Comment: подскажите как? или где можно об этом узнать? я не могу найти...

Comment: @Olesssya вот тут документация как использовать слайдер http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html

Comment: спасибо Вам огромное!!!